# EventBus event classes vs event types

Tags: android, eventbus

Использую библиотеку EventBus от greenrobot.

Есть два пути:

1. Под каждый евент создавать свой класс-евент
2. Создать один класс евент и в нем передавать тип евента и нужные
   данные

Как правильнее всего делать и почему ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что передавать по шине, зависит от конкретной ситуации и тех данных, что требуется передать, это не обязательно должен быть целый класс, чаще достаточно передачи простого примитивного типа. Хотя в примере приведен целый класс для передачи одного `String`, на практике это избыточно и класс-евент стоит использовать только для передачи в одно место данных разных типов (например `String`, `int` и какой-нибудь `boolean` за раз) или целых объектов разных типов. Для одной единицы данных создавать класс-евент не требуется. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345) для подробностей.

Однако делать какой то универсальный класс-евент для нескольких типов данных, некоторые из которых не требуются в месте назначения не самая лучшая идея из всех возможных. Следует слать только то, что требуется, зачем лишний "груз" - я не вижу никаких преимуществ в таком подходе.
Кроме того, приемник срабатывает по сигнатуре того, что отправлено. Если слать один и тот же класс-евент с разными данными и есть несколько получателей - неизвестно куда он будет доставлен, кто его перехватит и кто его должен был на самом деле получить. То есть он придет во все приемники, где сигнатура совпадает с вашим универсальным классом - это будет знатный и трудноконтролируемый бардак.

Answer (score 2):

Правильного ответа на ваш вопрос нет, т. к. он зависит от мнения. Мне лично удобнее использовать для ивентов разные классы. Почему? - Как минимум не нужно самому проверять *тип ивента* каждый раз, и слушателю приходят только те ивенты, на которые он подписан, а не все подряд.
Работать этот вариант тоже должен быстрее, т. к. не нужно дополнительно проверять тип ивента