# Как реализовать модель в MVP? Правильно ли я понимаю данный шаблон проектирования?

Tags: java, android, mvp

Собственно по началу всё понятно - мы имеем 3 части - model, present, view, но по реализации каждого из них в андроид у меня имеются вопросы.

На сколько я понял из прочитанного ранее

1. Все layout'ы заменяются фрагментами, таким образом мы имеем лишь 1 layout с 1 элементом - FrameLayout (это самое необычное для меня, понимаю логически, но все равно кажется, что что-то тут не так)
2. View

   - MainActivity класс с методом замены фрагмента
   - Класс для каждого фрагмента с начальными установками типа onClickListner'ов в onCreate'e и методами типа makeToast
3. Present

   - На каждый фрагмент по present'у
   - Могут ли в этой части быть дополнительные классы? Например класс, отвечающий за работу с пользовательскими данными?
4. Model

   - Я немного не понимаю как его реализовать так, что бы данные были доступны во всех present'ах? Возможно я неправильно понимаю то, как эта часть должна быть реализована и модель не должна ничего хранить в себе, а лишь получать данные из других мест (SharedPreferences, SQLite и т.д.)? В таком случае в каждом презенте надо просто создавать новую модель?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в двух словах:

1. View - максимально тупой объект (Activity, Fragment, View). Сам ничего не решает, управляется из Presenter'а. Имеет методы аля "показатьДанные(Данные данные)", "показатьОшибкуЗагрузки()". Layout - это просто вёрстка. Я бы его включил во View, так как интерфейс можно и без лэйаутов отображать.
2. Presenter - штука, в которой содержится вся логика приложения. Лучше, да, чтоб на каждую View был один Presenter (чтоб не был один огромный презентер).
3. Model - отвечает за получение и кэширование данных.

Реализаций и библиотек куча. Почитать на русском - загугли "android mvp habrahabr". Но вообще, если только начинаешь изучать Android, MVP не первая вещь, с которой нужно начинать обучение. Только ещё больше запутаешься в лайфсайкле =/

Comment: У меня самый большой вопрос сейчас - как передавать данные между различными фрагментами.

Какую вы бы посоветовали построить архитектуру первому простецкому, но серьезному андроид приложению? Какой паттер использовать?

Comment: @user3239600 я бы рекомендовал использовать шину данных, [такие библиотеки, как Otto или EventBus](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470899/177345) - это одновременно самый простой, прозрачный и самый эффективный способ, так как позволяет передавать что угодно напрямую.