# Как передать ссылку на объект в новый фрагмент?

Tags: android

Как передать ссылку на объект в новый фрагмент? 
Пытаюсь через `Bundle` - там нужно передавать `Serializable` объект, а как без этого?

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: не нравиться `Serializable `, юзайте `Parcelable`)

Comment: Передавайте в конструкторе фрагмента

Comment: Открываю фрагмент, в него нужно передать данные. Несколько ArrayList, пару String и ссылку куда потом вернуть результат.

Comment: Parcelable делай, плюс для всех объектов внутри имплементируй Parcelable. Там не сложно, глаза боятся - руки делают.

Comment: Лучше всего для таких целей использовать библиотеку [EventBus](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470899/177345)

Comment: EventBus я использую, но он же скорее сеттер, чем геттер, или есть возможность использовать его как геттер?

Comment: Решил просто добавив к класу, который передаю implements Serializable без переопределения методов и передал его через Bundle.Правда е знаю чем это мне грозит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода, как со списками делать Parcelable:

```
class TestA implements Parcelable {
    String field1;
    List<TestB> testBList;

    protected TestA(Parcel in) {
        field1 = in.readString();
        testBList = in.createTypedArrayList(TestB.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<TestA> CREATOR = new Creator<TestA>() {
        @Override
        public TestA createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestA(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TestA[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestA[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(field1);
        dest.writeTypedList(testBList);
    }
}

class TestB implements Parcelable {
    String field1;

    protected TestB(Parcel in) {
        field1 = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<TestB> CREATOR = new Creator<TestB>() {
        @Override
        public TestB createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestB(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TestB[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestB[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(field1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я решил просто добавив к класу implements Serializable без переопределения методов и передал его через Bundle.

Comment: Насколько я знаю более правильно в таких случаях Parcelable использовать. Хотя если у тебя обычные POJO, то можно и так оставить.