# Как получить данные из предыдущего фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Из `Fragment 1` запускается `Fragment 2`. 2ой отработал и должен вернуть `ArrayList` первому. Как лучше всего это реализовать?

Через `Activity`, которое их запускает?
Какие еще варианты?
Какой `BestPractice` метод для решения этой задачи?

Comment: библиотека [EventBus](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345)

Comment: Использую, но мне кажется, что это не самый лучший вариант

Comment: Самый лучший, особенно в коммуникации фрагмент - фрагмент. Средствами системы придется городить трехэтажную конструкцию на интерфейсах, с передачей фрагмент - активити - фрагмент, это очень скучно, но вы [можете озаботиться](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), конечно.