# Как вернуть данные между Fragment'ами?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `MainActivity`, у него есть контейнер, туда подгружаю `fragment A` и по нажатию на кнопку заменяю (replace) на `fragment B`, как мне вернуть данные из фрагмента В на А, типа `onActivityResult`, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Официальный [способ](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) или [EventBus](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345)

Comment: Как через `EventBus` это сделать, когда `fragment A` в `onPause`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainFragment - fragment A

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.click).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NextFragment fragment = new NextFragment();
                //Для идентификации именно этого результата используем код (например 120)
                fragment.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, 120);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cont, fragment).addToBackStack("null").commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Проверяем по коду нужный результат
        if(requestCode == 120){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                //Действия при возврате результата
                String value1 = data.getStringExtra("key1");
                String value2 = data.getStringExtra("key2");
            }else{
                //Действия при отмене
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fragment - B

public class NextFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_next, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.clickBack).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("key1", "value1");
            intent.putExtra("key2", "value2");
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Официальный [способ](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) или EventBus – pavlofff 5 июн в 12:51

Answer (score 0):

Набросал быстрый пример. Этот вариант подразумевает общение фрагментов через Activity. В примере фрагмент 2 передает данные фрагменту 1.

**Код MainActivity**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Добавляем фрагмент - F1
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fContainer, new F1(), "f1");
    ft.commit();
}


public void  replaceFragment1ToFragment2() {

    //Меняем фрагмент - F1 на фрагмент - F2
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fContainer, new F2());
    ft.commit();
}

public void  replaceFragment2ToFragment1(String text) {
    //Меняем фрагмент - F2 на фрагмент - F1
    //И передаем в F1 результаты из F2
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    F1 f1 = new F1();
    ft.replace(R.id.fContainer, f1);
    ft.commit();

    //Отправляем результаты
    f1.setData(text);
}

}
```

**Код первого фрагмента:**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class F1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

String text = "";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f1, container, false);
    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnStartF2);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Если нет результатов, оставляем оригинальное название кнопки
    if (!text.equals("")) b.setText(text);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment1ToFragment2();
}

public void setData(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

}
```

**Код второго фрагмента:**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class F2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f2, container, false);
    ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnStartF1)).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment2ToFragment1(
            ((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.textToF1)).getText().toString());
}
}
```

**Разметка MainActivity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Разметка первого фрагмента:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartF2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Запускаем F2"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Разметка второго фрагмента:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartF1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Возвращаем результат в F1"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textToF1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Отправим этот текст в F1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Пример не лучший и мне лень тестировать, но по всей видимости не рабочий. Помимо очевидных ошибок оптимизации, которые можно устранить (каждый раз создаются новые экземпляры фрагментов, вместо использования уже созданных и получения ссылок на виджет (`findViewById()`) при каждом обращении к виджету, вместо единоразового получения и использования полученного значения).

Comment: Основная проблема в том, что метод `setData()` вызывается после создания фрагмента, а в самом методе не производится никаких действий для обновления контента виджета - в общем виджет не обновится. Кроме того, такой подход демонстрирует сильное связывание компонентов и жесткие зависимости между ними - это плохое архитектурное решение, недостатки которого расписывать очень нудно и долго, но делать так не надо.

Comment: Для этой задачи существует оптимальный паттерн взаимодействия через интерфейсы и другие подходы будут или хуже (за исключением использования шины данных, как EventBus) или не рабочими, как данный пример (хотя его и можно заставить работать, но при сколько нибудь сложном проекте он доставит много хлопот).

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы!

Comment: На самом деле лучшим решением коммуникации между всеми компонентами приложения будет использование библиотеки EventBus или аналогов