# Как из Fragment запустить другой Fragment чтобы он отработав вернул результат (как startActivityForResult)?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как из `Fragment1` запустить `Fragment2` чтобы он отработав вернул результат 1му фрагменту(как `startActivityForResult`)? 
 Я знаю, как вернуть результат отработки второго фрагмента в Activity, но как передать эти данные именно в `Fragment1`?

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос хорошо описан на startandroid.ru. См. [Урок 106. Android 3. Fragments. Взаимодействие с Activity](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html). Вам нужен последний раздел **Обработка в Activity события из фрагмента** он в конце.

Comment: Не то. В описании подразумевается, что 2 фрагмента на данный момент активны, а в моем случае первый должен запустить второй, а когда второй отработает, он должен передать первому результат.

Comment: В [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531790/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-fragment%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) набросал небольшой пример смены фрагментов в рамках одного контейнера. В примере фрагмент 2 передает данные фрагменту 1.