# Обновление View у Fragment через другой Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, view

Есть ПервыйФрагмент, который отображает несколько layout с набором картинок и текста, и ВторойФрагмент, который является настройками предыдущего. При нажатии на чекбокс во втором фрагменте, необходимо скрыть (изменить видимость) одного из layout в первом. Изменения должны быть динамические, так как второй фрагмент не запускается по вызову с ответом

Comment: Есть множество способов, советую попробовать с самого простого - банального слушателя (паттерн Observable)

Comment: @abbath0767 а можно пример какой-нибудь показать, а то я пока в этом слаб(

Comment: Вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531790/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-fragment%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) есть пример.

Comment: Очень НЕ советую использовать библиотеку EventBus, по крайней мере на начальном этапе точно. Реализацию того же паттерна можете найти в самой стандартной андроид библиотеке - например метод onClick(View view) из интерфейса OnClickListener(). Когда удастся реализовать подобный способ и поймете что возможно он вам не подходит - я не думаю что составит труда найти и остальные

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас случай настроек, то, наверное, проще всего будет использовать `SharedPreferences` для записи значения чекбокса и слушатель изменения оных во фрагменте, в котором менять собственно видимость нужной вьюхи.