# вернуть результат из onAcitivtyResult активити С в onAcitivtyResult активити А

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

есть активити А в ней выполняю startForResult активити В, потом в ActivityResult обрабатываю результат, из активити А стартуем фрагмент, который  стартует автивити С, из С стартует startForResult активити В, и в ActivityResult С приходит результат, теперь хотелось бы прокинуть этот результат в ActivityResult активити А. вот как провести последнюю операцию немного не понимаю. код ниже
активити А

```
 public void startForResult(int requestCode) {
        if (requestCode==1) {
            //do something
        } 
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == xx ) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

далее стартует фрагмент и в нем запускается активити С.Пробовал применить rx, создать Observable и подписаться на него  когда получаем результат, но не пошло. подскажите какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Зачем вы удалили вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573039/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-edittext ? Чтобы никто, кроме вас не нашел решение этой проблемы? Как эгоистично.

Comment: Тогда надо удалять 75% ваших вопросов

Comment: Ну, это же ваша логика...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо

1. Запускать актвити `C` также через `startActivityForResult`.
2. Далее, после запуска `B` из `C` и возвращения результата в `B` вызовется `onActivityResult` в `C`.
3. В нём уже вы сможете установить результат через`setResult()` для активити `C`, закрыть её через `finish()`
4. И после этого получить результат в вызове `onActivityResult` в `A`

Answer (score 2):

При таком сложном взаимодействии разумнее использовать шину данных, [вроде EventBus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470899/177345), так связь между компонентами будет во много более простой, линейной и надежной.

реактивное программирование в решении такой задачи несколько избыточно и имеет смысл, только если весь проект построен на его принципах.

Answer (score 0):

Прокидывать из C в A. По вашему это хороший код?

Если вы сейчас такое делаете то в будущем вы надумаете вообще прокидывать из Z в A. А это чревато тем что в зависимости от тяжести Активити или фрагментов пока вы создадите допустим C. то A может просто удалиться, так как памяти может не хватить.

В данном случае может быть и такое. В любом случае разумно запустить новый активити A из C. И передать через Intent все нужные данные. А все остальные активити закрыть. Чтобы не было утечки памяти