# Передача ссылки на объект в другую активность Android

Tags: java, android

Задача:
В первой активности **Activity1** мы создаем экземпляр класса **VeryFatClass**:

**VeryFatClass** obj = new **VeryFatClass**();

Проводим с ним необходимые действия, и хотим передать именно этот объект в **Activity2**.

проблема:
Поля класса **VeryFatClass** это по большей части другие объекты, в которых поля так же представляют из себя объекты ( и в некоторых из них поля так же объекты).

Каким образом организовать контроль над объектом **VeryFatClass** из более 2-х активностей? текущее мое решение, я использую статичное поле и шаблон синглтон, но мне кажется это не совсем правильно, потому что я должен надеяться на то, что уборщик не снесет созданный мной экземпляр в первой активности. Есть ли способ обезопасить себя от такого? читал про *Parcelable*, но как я понял, мне пришлось бы каждое поле, в котором есть объект делать как *Parcelable*?

Comment: Передавать объекты между активити лучше и проще всего [через EventBus](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345) или аналоги. `Parcelable` да, нужно разложить объект на примитивные типы.

Comment: Казалось бы такая простая задача, а требует изучения библиотек или, что еще хуже, написания кода в размере от 30% от размера класса только для того, чтобы просто передать этот объект в другую активность. Р - рационализм (нет)

Comment: Проблема не в платформе, а в Вашей архитектуре. Пользуйтесь слоем модели для хранения объекта и забирайте этот же объект из модели во второй `Activity`. Способ с `Parcelable` может не сработать на Android Nougat из-за ограничения размера транзакции (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) + в любой момент система может убить процесс приложения и объект потеряется.