# Какие отличия EventBus от BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, eventbus

Добрый день. Недавно начал ознакамливаться с новомодными либами и сейчас подошла очередь EventBus от greenrobot.

**Собственно вопрос:** В чём отличие данной либы от стандартного `BroadcastReceiver` ? Ведь используя стандартный ресивер, мы также можем отправлять сообщения(с помощь интентов) из какого-либо места и получать их в нужном месте, при этом даже не нужно создавать модель для данных, ведь интенет можно подписать.

Поправьте меня, если я что-то не так понимаю или неправильно выражаюсь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В одном из комментариев прозвучало мнение, что "Любые задачи, которые Вы хотите решить, используя EventBus, можно решить без него". Рассмотрим, что нам предлагает система.

Транспортировочные контейнеры данных Android, такие, как `Bundle` или `Intent` имеют довольно ограниченный набор передаваемых типов данных (примитивные типы, массивы и коллекции примитивных типов, строки, объекты реализующие интерфейс `Parcelable` (`Serializable`)).
Для передачи прочих объектов (а ООП подрразумевает, что это основной тип данных) требуется их парцелизация (сериализация), что всегда ведет к дополнительному коду (часто довольно объемному) и не всегда возможно (как класс `Drawable`, который нужно преобразовать в `Bitmap` перед парцелизацией). Все это приводит к тому, что требуется много дополнительного кода для выполнения простой задачи - передача объекта между компонентами приложения.
Далее, транспортные контейнеры, как уже было сказано выше, передают ограниченный набор типов и для передачи нескольких значений разных типов их требуется упаковать (а затем и извлекать) отдельно, что при некотором объеме данных (например информация контакта, который может включать много полей) так же приводит к вынужденному увеличению набираемого кода.
Сами механизмы межкомпонентного взаимодействия в приложении так же довольно громоздки и местами многоступенчаты (как передача из фрагмента в фрагмент).

Для решения всех этих неудобств и используется шина данных (как EventBus), которая позволяет самым простым образом передавать любые типы данных между компонентами без всякой предварительной подготовки, а так же отсылать данные получателю, который еще не существует или не готов принимать данные в момент передачи (sticky event).

Таким образом, без данной библиотеки, безусловно, можно обойтись, но она решает определенный круг очевидных проблем, делая межкомпонентное взаимодействие проще. Абстрактным примером ее "ненужности" можно привести желание копать лопатой, когда можно вскопать трактором - при определенном объеме работ выбор становится очевидным.

Таким образом я не могу согласится с мнениями из другого ответа насчет ненужности, плохого архитектурного решения и бритвы Оккама, в определенных условиях такое решение будет оптимальным. По поводу затруднений отладки тоже не совсем понимаю, в чем они. Единственная проблема, которая может произойти - данные не приходят по назначению. Решение этой проблемы очевидно из неправильного использования самого инструмента и тут уж, по прошлой аналогии - не умеешь управлять трактором, копай гектар лопатой ..

**Теперь по самому вопросу**.
Во первых, создание объекта-модели не обязательно (и избыточно) для передачи данных имеющих собственный тип (только для набора разнотиповых данных) - шине все равно, какой именно объект отправить, она отлично доставит по назначению и примитивный `int` без всякой обертки.
Во вторых, `Broadcast` - широковещательные сообщения, "весть" о них рассылается на всю систему, что при межкомпонентном взаимодействии внутри приложения несколько чрезмерно, вспоминается помянутая бритва Оккама. Да, существует `LocalBroadcastManager` и им можно пользоваться внутри приложения, если все изложенное в начале ответа вы считаете допустимой "жертвой" на алтарь нативных инструментов коммуникаций данных.

Подробнее [про EventBus и его назначение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/177345)

Comment: Ох, спасибо за ответ. По поводу передачи объектов и их сериализации - уже сталкивался с таким, что приходится городить большое количество кода, чтобы отправить/принять объект, в то время как с использованием `EventBus` это решается в несколько строчек

Answer (score 2):

Когда то уже отвечал на аналогичный вопрос, но мне не в лом - повторюсь:

самое главное отличие *EventBus* от *Broadcast*'ов в том, что `EventBus` - это либа для внутрипроцессного обмена данными, в частности, вы не сможете обмениваться данными между `Activity` и внешним `Service` и тем паче между разными приложениями, а *Broadcast* легко преодолевает эти границы, поскольку пользуется средствами самой оси. По крайней мере так работает `EventBus` от *GreenRobot* - есть и другие `EventBus`, которые обеспечивают межпроцессное взаимодействия - [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: Хм, спасибо за ответ. Что Вы понимаете под "внешним `Service`"? Сервис созданный в данном приложении, но из другого активити или сервис из другого приложения?

Comment: Service с поименованным процессом: `android:process="string"`

Comment: Хочу добавить, что `EventBus` является плохим архитектурным решением. Любые задачи, которые Вы хотите решить, используя `EventBus`, можно решить без него. Используя его, появляются множество затруднений с отладкой ошибок и визуальным пониманием кода.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov - не могу не согласиться с вами. Он противоречит принципу [Бритвы Оккама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бритва_Оккама) - создает ненужные сущности, буквально на пустом месте

Comment: давайте не будем делать резких заявлений. EventBus - это пример парадигмы событийно-ориентированного программирования. С таким же успехом можно заявить, что функциональное программирование - это плохое архитектурное решение и всякие лямбды и RxJava - это лишние вещи, без которых так же можно обойтись. Важно уметь применять такие вещи на практике, а плохие решения создают разработчики, которые применять этого не умеют.