# Вызов метода по событию , регистрация на событие

Tags: java, android, события

Как на java реализовать что бы по определённому событию вызывались определённые методы, которые подписаны на это событие.
То есть если нажали button1 в наш метод (контроллер) передалось что произошло событие Events1 и в соответствие с этим событием вызываются методы , которые подписаны на это событие.

Comment: А готовые библиотеки не подойдут?

Comment: у кнопки setOnClickListener. Если хочется свой велосипед - паттерн Observer

Comment: Пожалуй один из лучших ответов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470923/211117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам вполне подойдет концепция EventBus (шины данных) https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus.

Она нужна для того, чтобы независимые компоненты могли общаться между собой путем отправки и приема событий.

Вы можете посмотреть в сторону готовых библиотек, а можете попробовать реализовать шину сами, это не сложно.

### Создайте аннотацию EventReceiver:

```
@Documented
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface EventReceiver
{
}
```

### Создайте класс EventChannel:

```
public abstract class EventChannel
{
    private EventChannel(){}

    private static final Set<Object> receivers = new HashSet<>();
    private static final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());

    public static void connect(Object receiver) {
        receivers.add(receiver);
    }

    public static void disconnect(Object receiver) {
        receivers.remove(receiver);
    }

    public static void send(Object data) {
        for (Object receiver : receivers) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (Method method : receiver.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(EventReceiver.class)) {
                        handler.post(() -> {
                            try { method.invoke(receiver, data);}
                            catch (Exception ignored) {}
                        });
                     }
                 }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Всё, что вам нужно чтобы отправить событие:

```
EventChannel.send(new CustomData());
```

Всё, что вам нужно, чтобы поймать событие - подключиться к шине данных в классе-приёмнике: `EventChannel.connect(this);` и определить метод с аннотацией `EventReceiver`:

```
@EventReceiver
public void onEventReceive(CustomData data) {
   //.обработка отправленных данных.//
}
```

Не забывайте также и отключиться в нужный момент `EventChannel.disconnect(this);`

Вы сможете передавать данные любого типа, а также подписываться на получение любых данных. Методов, помеченных аннотацией `EventReceiver` может быть несколько, если вы захотите принимать разные объекты.