# Передача данных из модального окна Android

Tags: java, android

Как из модального окна передать данные в ediText находящиеся в приложении? 
Есть класс модального окна. 
Нужно передать от туда данные в класс MakeOrderActivity

Comment: Если данные передать надо, а зависимости внедрять не хочется, то - EventBus: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700073/261767

Comment: Добавьте код. Модальное окно можно сделать по разному и по разному туда передавать/получать из него данные. Например для диалог-фрагмента вызываемого из фрагмента есть TargetFragment, а для обычного диалога можно просто контекст к активити кастануть или интерфейс прокинуть.